# Matrix smallest number

Tags: c#

So this code should work, but i cant figure out the problem.
It worked me once before... But now i only get back 0 as a result.
I know it should be obvious but i cant see it.

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)

        {Console.WriteLine("The SmallestNumber in the given matrix is : {0}", SmallestNumber());
        Console.ReadKey();           
        }

        public static int SmallestNumber()
        {
            int n = 10;
            int m = 10;

            int[,] TempMatrix = new int[n, m];            
            Random r = new Random();

            int smallest = TempMatrix[0,0]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    TempMatrix[i, j] = r.Next(10, 3000);

                    if (smallest > TempMatrix[i,j])
                    {
                        smallest = TempMatrix[i, j];
                    }

              Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t", TempMatrix[i, j]));

                }

             }
            return smallest;              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wops sorry i tried to submit it for like 15 min then accidentally hit post sorry.

Comment: The problem seems to be in line int smallest = TempMatrix[0,0];. The matrix values has not been yet assigned, thus smallest will be initialized with 0(default int value).

Comment: You initialise `smallest` to `TempMatrix[0,0];` before you changed any values in `TempMatrix`. Guess what the default values in `TempMatrix` will be at that point... Instead, initialise `smallest` to `int.MaxValue`

Comment: Or change the condition into `if (smallest > TempMatrix[i,j] || smallest == 0)`, i.e. if `TempMatrix[i,j]` is less than `smallest` or if `smallest` is a default value

Comment: Ah i see now! I thought when i say : smallest = TempMatrix[0,0]; I am initializing the  place regardless of the value what it holds. Or at least this was my idea to make;

Comment: `return TempMatrix.OfType<int>().Min;`

Comment: Thanks the quick responses, it is working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize `smallest`, `TempMatrix[0,0]` has the value `0`. All the random numbers you generate are between `10` and `3000`, so all the numbers in the matrix are greater than `smallest`, since it is `0`.

Setting `smallest` initially to `int.MaxValue` should solve the problem.